# Is it possible to get the "to" of a transaction in solidity?

Tags: solidity, transactions

I would like to get the "to" address of a `tx` at any call depth within a transaction, is this possible in solidity?

As far as I can tell the `tx` object does not expose any attribute to do so.

If not is there has an ERC/EIP at least been proposed for it? I tried searching but couldn't find any.

Comment: It is not possible as far I know. however, I think if tx.origin == msg.sender then the address of the current contract is the "to" from the tx. IDK if there is any risk in using this logic. verify it and  use it on your own responsibility :)

Comment: @MajdTL thanks for the comment, however, I'm aware of that and also it only works at 0 call depth i.e. within the immediate context of the contract that is called by the EOA; that's why my question specifically states "at any call depth within a transaction".